# Error in .lm.fit(x, y) : NA/NaN/Inf in 'x' in R

Tags: r, statistics, regression, data-modeling, analysis

I have been trying to find the correlations between all the categorical and numerical in my dataset using association from greybox in the following way-

```
library(readxl)
library(timeDate)
library(greybox)
library(dplyr)
library(mice)
library(Hmisc)

carData33 <- read.csv("carData.csv")
#removing the first column since its not necessary, it represents the ID number
carData33 <- carData33[,c(2:15)]
#replacing NA with 0
carData33[is.na(carData33)] <-0

assoc(carData33)
```

the main objective is to do regression by selecting variables with correlation values.

Bt while doing so, the error that pops up is -

```
Error in .lm.fit(x, y) : NA/NaN/Inf in 'x'
In addition: Warning message:
In .lm.fit(x, y) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

the dataset is as follows-
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhjwR.png

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example, with data in a usable format, that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: I am attaching the link to the csv file for better reference. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rS-lc_cdAESGixQVmYJjUfzg-I7Bx5ru/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use as.factor() on the columns containing categorial data.
Like `test$manufacturer <- as.factor(test$manufacturer)`

Comment: can you make me the understand the reason of doing so?

Comment: Because categorical data in R is represented by factors. Without this conversion the column are filled with character values which aren't evaluated as categorical values.

Comment: There are also some useful parameters to as.factor() as well as the global option 'options(stringsAsFactors=TRUE)' which should be treated with care though. The stringsAsFactors also exists as parameter in data.frame() and read.csv().